# PostGIS - Assign value based on ST_Intersects and ST_Area

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have two data sets, US County boundaries (tiger.counties2020) and parcel data (temp.parcel). I would like to assign a county geoid to the parcel data based on a majority of the parcel polygon being within a county boundary. In some cases these parcel polygons overlap multiple counties, but I would like to assign the geoid to the county that the parcel has most of its area in.

```
UPDATE
    temp.parcel
SET
    geoid_majority = upd.geoid
FROM
    tiger.counties2020 upd
WHERE
    upd.geoid = '00000'
    AND ST_Intersects(temp.parcel.geom_polygon, upd.geom) = TRUE
    AND 51 <= 100 *(
        ST_Area(
            ST_Intersection(temp.parcel.geom_polygon, upd.geom)
        ) / LEAST(
            ST_Area(temp.parcel.geom_polygon),
            ST_Area(upd.geom)
        )
    )
    AND geoid_majority IS NULL;
```

is what has yielded me the most results, however I still have parcels with a NULL value for geoid_majority

Comment: It is answered on [gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394705/how-to-optimize-postgis-intersection-query). You query is not working because the overlapped area is less than 51%. You must instead compute the intersection area and keep the largest one

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/179778/37568 this answer covers the case when overlap is less than 50%